# Data display on PHP (Select Query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which contains:

```
transaction_id | the_pet | name_of_the_owners
    1               dog        shiela
    2               dog         ben
    3               dog         alice
    4               cat         jonathan
```

and on my query:

```
$query="select * from table ORDER BY name_of_the_owner limit 5";
$r=mysqli_query($query);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td><a href='../php/ownersname.php?the_pet=".$row['the_pet']."'>".$row['the_pet']."</a></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }
```

However, when I use the $query, it shows all the data from the table.
What I need is this:

```
     the_pet
  dog (hyperlink)
  cat (hyperlink)
```

So whenever I click on the hyperlink, the name_of_the owners will be shown in another page

for the dog when clicked

```
name_of_the_owners
    shiela
    ben
    alice
```

I already used

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(transaction_id) as transaction_id, the_pet GROUP BY the_pet, name_of_the_owners;
```

but when I clicked on the hyperlink, it doesn't show the owners. :(

Comment: @Fred: yes.but when i use the select max the hyperlink does not function :( which is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if I understand it right you dont want to show duplicates right ?

I think the best way to do this, is to change your select query to

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT the_pet FROM table";
```

and if you dont want to do that you could filter a array for duplicates

like so:

```
$arr = array('php','jsp','asp','php','asp');
$unique = array_unique($arr);
print_r($dups);
```

both will do the trick!